# Move object file to another directory using MSVC

Tags: opengl, visual-c++, vscode-tasks

I use Microsoft Visual C++ to compiler my project in VSCode. There is my tasks.json file.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: cl.exe build active file",
            "command": "cl.exe",
            "args": [
                "/Zi",
                "/EHsc",

                "/I${workspaceFolder}\\Dependencies\\GLFW\\include",
                "/I${workspaceFolder}\\Dependencies\\GLEW\\include",
                
                "opengl32.lib", "user32.lib", "gdi32.lib",
                "shell32.lib", "kernel32.lib", "msvcrt.lib", "msvcmrt.lib",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\Dependencies\\GLFW\\lib-vc2019\\glfw3.lib",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\Dependencies\\GLEW\\lib\\Release\\x64\\glew32s.lib",

                "/nologo",
                
                "/Fe:",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\build\\source.exe",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\OpenGL\\src\\*.cpp"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$msCompile"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "compiler: cl.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I compile my project, I have 3 files source.exe, source.ilk, source.pdb at "${workspaceFolder}\build\", and 2 files source.obj, vc140.pdb at "${workspaceFolder}\OpenGL\src\".
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0eYV.png)
I want 2 files source.obj, vc140.pdb at "${workspaceFolder}\build\", how do I do that.
Another question, I create "Shader.h" and "Shader.cpp" at "${workspaceFolder}\OpenGL\src\", the same directory as "source.cpp", when I compile my project, I have one more "Shader.obj" at "${workspaceFolder}\OpenGL\src\".
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dUwX.png)
How can I move all obj file to "${workspaceFolder}\build\".
Many thanks!

Comment: You may be looking for [`/Fo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fo-object-file-name) compiler option. It sets the directory for intermediate files, .obj files among them. And `/Fd` for .pdb file.

Comment: I have solved the problem with /Fo and /Fd, but I received many link warning 4217. Thanks, @IgorTandetnik.

Comment: Well, the message for [this warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-warning-lnk4217) says "Remove the `__declspec(dllimport)` modifier to resolve this warning." Have you tried resolving the warning this way?

Comment: But I use the static library and I defined GLEW_STATIC at top of source.cpp.